# What is the purpose of the existence of the QQueue container?

Tags: qt, qlist

I started working with Qt since a bit, and I have been using the [QQueue](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlist.html) class as a replacement for [std::queue](http://fr.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue). Though today I figured that I was able to use the [pop_front](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlist.html#pop_front), [pop_back](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlist.html#pop_back), [push_front](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlist.html#push_front) and [push_back](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlist.html#push_back) functions from the [QList](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlist.html) class on a QQueue object. Wondering why you would be able to use those functions (especially *pop_back* and *push_front*) on a queue, I checked the Qt documentation, and figured that QQueue was inheriting QList.

For me the main interest of a queue is to act as a queue: enqueuing stuff in the back, dequeuing stuff in the front. But when I kept on reading the documentation, I figured that the [enqueue](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qqueue.html#enqueue) and [dequeue](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qqueue.html#dequeue) functions were just equivalents to the [append](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlist.html#append) and [takeFirst](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlist.html#takeFirst) functions of the QList class. Even the [head](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qqueue.html#head) function is identical to the [first](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlist.html#first) function of QList. On top of that, the possibility to use functions such as *pop_back* and *push_front* completly breaks the initial logic of a queue for me, while the documentation itself presents the QQueue class as a queue container:

> The QQueue class is a generic container that provides a queue.
>
> QQueue is one of Qt's generic container classes. It implements a queue data structure for items of a same type.
>
> A queue is a first in, first out (FIFO) structure. Items are added to the tail of the queue using enqueue() and retrieved from the head using dequeue(). The head() function provides access to the head item without removing it.

Is there anything I am missing about the purpose of the existence of the QQueue class? By that I mean, why was this queue container created so that it can do more than what a queue is supposed to do? And as the QQueue class seems to be able to work the exact same way as a QList, is there any reason to use a QQueue over a QList?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the [containers description](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html#the-container-classes):

> `QStack` and `QQueue` are convenience classes that provide [LIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) and [FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)) semantics.

The only difference is the **additional methods** you mentioned:

- `QQueue`: [`enqueue`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqueue.html#enqueue), [`dequeue`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqueue.html#dequeue), [`head`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqueue.html#head).
- `QStack`: [`push`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstack.html#push), [`pop`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstack.html#pop), [`top`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstack.html#top).

The main point is a more semantically suitable and **intuitive method naming**.

Otherwise:

- `QQueue` is identical to its base class `QList`.
- `QStack` is identical to its base class `QVector`.

See it for yourself, take a look at the **source code** – nothing extra is present in these classes:

- [`qqueue.h`](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/src/corelib/tools/qqueue.h) / [`qqueue.cpp`](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/src/corelib/tools/qqueue.cpp)
- [`qstack.h`](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/src/corelib/tools/qstack.h) / [`qstack.cpp`](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/src/corelib/tools/qstack.cpp)

Comment: There is a not-so-subtle, but important difference: QQueue is a QList, QStack is a QVector.

Comment: If you are going to clarify that, it will be a good idea to also include the ramifications visave `QList`.

Comment: what do you think, why is `QQueue` inherited from `QList` and ` QStack` inherited from `QVector`? i cannot see why both couldn't have been `QList`s.

Answer (score 2):

`QQueue` itself inherits from `QList` and simply adds a few methods, already present in `QList` under different names. There is no point to using it other than syntax sugar.